# Mysql: weird behaviour with aggregation function

Tags: mysql, sql

**I have:** table with about 100 million rows:

```
my_table
  |-id
  |-created
  |-..
```

**I need:** to select minimum created value;

**The first approach: (extra slow, about infinity)**

```
SELECT MIN(created) FROM my_table;
```

**The second approach: (extra fast, about 100 milliseconds)**

```
SELECT MIN(id) FROM my_table INTO @min_id;
SELECT MAX(id) FROM my_table INTO @max_id;
SELECT MIN(created) FROM my_table WHERE id IN (@min_id, @max_id); //WHY THIS SELECT IS SO FAST?
```

**Question:** *WHY?! Why the first approach is so slow and the second so fast? It seems the same operation?*

Comment: This is magic of index :)

Comment: Because your `id` is most probably an auto increment id and could very well even be primary key. `created` is not. Indexes in action

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I still cant grasp why the 3d row of the 2nd query is so fast.

Comment: @Sadikhasan but how index is related to the `MIN` function in 3rd row?

Comment: Because in first approach search from whole table and in second approach search from min(id) and max(id).

Comment: @Sadikhasan but search from min_id to max_id is the search through whole table

Comment: In second approach you apply filter on id so not search whole table that search limited record which satisfy condition

Comment: VB: no, you don't search "FROM" and "TO", you search only those two values. There is a difference between `IN` and `BETWEEN`.

Comment: The second approach is plain wrong as it only gets the minimum `created` from *two* specific rows: the one with the lowest id and the one with the highest id. It does ***not*** calculate the `min(created)`for *all* rows.

Comment: @Konerak yes, that's the answer to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing `IN` and `BETWEEN`

```
SELECT MIN(id) FROM my_table INTO @min_id;
SELECT MAX(id) FROM my_table INTO @max_id;
SELECT MIN(created) FROM my_table WHERE id IN (@min_id, @max_id); //WHY THIS SELECT IS SO FAST?
```

That last query will only read the first row and the last row, and take the minimum 'created' value of those two rows, since `WHERE id IN (@min_id, @max_id)` can also be written as `WHERE id = @min_id or id =  @max_id`

Now, if your table is ordered, this might actually give the correct solution. But if it isn't, it will produce the wrong results.

Answer (score 1):

You have no index on the `created` so to find min it must scan all the records. And obviously you have index on `id` (looks like it's primary key) so it finds min and max very fast. Then it just choose min of 2 values.

Comment: may you explain `just choose min of 2` with more details please. It seems to me that MySQL should make the same number of compares in both 1st and 2nd cases.\

Comment: Because your last select only needs to inspect two values, instead of 100 million. Your where clause has an IN which only has two values. Do note that, unless the table is sorted, your result might be wrong...

Comment: The third query first finds (with index) 2 records with ids=min_id and max_id. Then choses minimum from the 2